# How to compute the intersection between two rectangles in simple way using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, intersection

Suppose I have two rectangle that intersect somehow. The two rectangles are shown in the following picture :

[image]

1. The *green* rectangle is **ABCD**.
2. The *red* rectangle is **A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>C<sub>3</sub>D<sub>3</sub>**

I want to compute the the *octagon* inside ? (or hexagon or in this case heptagon)

What I succeeded to do until now is to use the function [*lineintersect*](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30502-find-intersection-of-two-lines), but it seems very looong and heavy. There is definitely a better way. Do you have any functions to simplify that ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compute?  Do you want to compute the area? intersection points?

Comment: the intersection points ...

Comment: Do you have the Mapping Toolbox?  Check out `polyxpoly`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html

Comment: and that answers my question :D :D thank you so much @rayryeng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the Mapping Toolbox.  The simplest way to achieve the intersection points between two polygons is to use the [`polyxpoly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html) function.

The prototype looks like this:

```
[xi,yi] = polyxpoly(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

`x1` and `y1` are the `x` and `y` coordinates that define the polygon of the first shape and `x2` and `y2` are the coordinates that define the polygon of the second shape.  These are 1D vectors and the result gives you `x` and `y` coordinates stored in `xi` and `yi` that give you the intersection points of the two polygons together.

Here's an example of using the function:

```
% Define and fill a rectangular area in the plane
xlimit = [3 13];
ylimit = [2  8];
xbox = xlimit([1 1 2 2 1]);
ybox = ylimit([1 2 2 1 1]);
mapshow(xbox,ybox,'DisplayType','polygon','LineStyle','none')

% Define and display a two-part polyline
x = [0 6  4  8 8 10 14 10 14 NaN 4 4 6 9 15];
y = [4 6 10 11 7  6 10 10  6 NaN 0 3 4 3  6];
mapshow(x,y,'Marker','+')

% Intersect the polyline with the rectangle
[xi, yi] = polyxpoly(x, y, xbox, ybox);
mapshow(xi,yi,'DisplayType','point','Marker','o');
```

We get:

[image]

<sup>Source: [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html)</sup>